# How to run the flutter application in the background even after the application removed from the ram

Tags: android, flutter, background-process, background-task

I want to implement the feature (Example images were attached below) in the flutter application. I want that if I started a service, then it will not be killable till the service end. It will show a notification like this that the application service is still active.
I want a service like this, the application continuously uploads the location of the user to my server in the background continuously.
I tried the plugin [work_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager). But this plugin runs the service every 15 minutes (15 minutes is the minimum time we can set).

**Example of my requirements:**

**1. Here in my android task there is no application running.**

[image]

**2. But still, this application is running because the service was enabled.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`flutter_background_services`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) plugin. You can start a foreground service which will keep running even if the app is terminated.
Here, you can set the interval as low as 1 second.

It is using STICKY service, which basically means, it will restart the service if terminated by the OS.

Comment: another query is that, can we run multiple services?